# how to add a Run Button and Compile Button on the toolbar in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to add a "**Run**" button and a "**Compile**" button on the toolbar so that I may not have to Press <kbd>CTRL + F5</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL + Shift + D</kbd>

Comment: You need to have the `Standard Toolbar` enabled. It's usually under view -> toolbars -> Standard

Comment: It's already enabled but don't have have Run button instead there is a Debug button

Answer (score 10, accepted):

View -> Toolbars -> Customuze -> Commands Tab -> Toolbar Option -> Add Command

You can add the **Start Without Debugging** command from the **Debug** group:

[image]

To compile you probably want the **Build.Compile** command:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Enable Standart toolbar

```
View - Toolbars - Standart
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply activate the "Build" toolbar in View > Toolbars. This adds the *Start Without Debugging,* *Build Project,* and *Build Solution* buttons to the Toolbar.

The different selections listed in the View>Toolbars submenu appear to be toggles not complete tool bars. At some point they must have moved the build buttons to their own section and out of the Standard tools.